# Mouse hover with ember

Tags: ember.js, view, hover, mouse

I am new to Ember. I want when i hover the mouse over a .png file to be transparent and to exist there on the right corner an 'X' button and when you press it, it will be removed from the store. Any ideas or any example? I have these files:

showactivecamp.hbs

```
<style type="text/css">


    .image {
        width: 190px;
        height: 190px;
        opacity: 1;

    }

    .image:hover {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    i.fa-remove {
    @extend . image : hover;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #808080;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 8px;
        padding: 2px;
        z-index: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


</style>

<div class="thmb-prev">

                    <button type="button" class="fa fa-remove" {{action "removeCampaign" on="click"}}>


                    </button>
                    <img src="/assets/images/photos/media2.png" class="image" alt="">

                </div>
```

controllers\showactivecamp.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['campaign'],

    actions: {
        removeCampaign: function (campaign) {

            var camp = this.get('model');
            camp.deleteRecord();
            camp.save();

        }
    },

    getactivecamp: function () {
        return this.store.findAll('campaign');
    }.property()

});
```

views\showactivecamp.js
    import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.View.extend({

    click: function (evt) {
        this.get('controller').send('click', this.get('campaign'));
    }

 });
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  I'm willing to help, but want to see some effort on your part too.  Good luck, and welcome to SO.

Comment: This is a css issue, as for removing a record from the store look at routes and how to handle actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this would be best handled with a CSS solution rather than creating the unnecessary views in Javascript

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jecew/1

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! Btw is there anywhere to run online your project? https://github.com/alexdiliberto/emberconf-2014-demo

Comment: No, not right now but it's really easy to just clone the repository yourself and run `ember serve`. It's a bit outdated the demo as it's on an older CLI version but the principles will still work perfectly if you need help with your application's analytics handling. When I have time, I'll be porting the demo over to the latest version of EmberCLI

Answer (score 0):

You posted your code but not mentioned about the issue. I am not sure what is the issue you are getting.

Have a look into this jsbin http://jsbin.com/xumomu/1. I have used FixtureAdapter.

UPDATE:

http://jsbin.com/xumomu/2/

I have wrapped image and close icon in a view called 'image'. X icon will be shown on mouse enter and will be hidden on mouse leave using jQuery.

```
As Ember guide says, Use View when you need sophisticated handling of user events.
```

I suggest you to go through documentation to get clear idea about View and Event handling in ember.

Comment: yes something like this. But i want the x button to appear when i hover the image.